# Duplicate records with different codes. Select codes that have no 'useful' and at least one 'not found'

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, duplicates

I have a database where accounts get rechecked and their status changes. They only have one bill date but their account can have multiple statuses. I am using **postgreSQL 9.2**

For instance we have these accounts

```
Account number | Last Name | First Name | bill_date  | code
100001             Doe         John      06-01-2013    useful
100001             Doe         John      06-01-2013    useful
100001             Doe         John      06-01-2013    not found
100001             Doe         John      06-01-2013    useful

Account number | Last Name | First Name | bill_date  | code
100034             Jane         Mary      07-12-2013    notfound
100034             Jane         Mary      07-12-2013    not found
100034             Jane         Mary      07-12-2013    error
100034             Jane         Mary      07-12-2013    error

Account number | Last Name | First Name | bill_date  | code
100021             Smith         Mark      01-11-2013    error
100021             Smith         Mark      01-11-2013    error
100021             Smith         Mark      01-11-2013    error
100021             Smith         Mark      01-11-2013    error

Account number | Last Name | First Name | bill_date  | code
10009             Queen         Mark      01-11-2013    error
10009             Queen         Mark      01-11-2013    useful
10009             Queen         Mark      01-11-2013    error
10009             Queen         Mark      01-11-2013    error
```

I am trying to have my query give me results on these codes

I want a count of all the records that have **at least one useful** code obtained

I want a count of all the records that have **no useful** but at least one **not found** codes obtained.

And a count of all the records the have **only error** codes obtained.

So my result would look like this

```
Useful  2   --> John doe, and mark queen
Not Found 1 --> mary jane
Error 1     --> mark smith
```

The problem that I am running into is selecting the records that have **no useful** but at least one **not found**. I am filtering my query but when I search for codes that are not found it will still return the useful codes since it is with the same account (John doe).

here is my query below

```
select

     case
          when code in ('useful') then code
          else null
     end as code,
     account_number,
     bill_date

from(



select distinct
            code,
            account_number,
            bill_date

      joins for tables go here

           and code in ('useful', 'not found', 'error')



            and bill_date > current_date - interval '2 month'
            and bill_date < current_date



            order by account_number,code, bill_date
)A
```

This will return all of the not found codes and the useful codes will then be null.  So john doe's account would still show in a test query as this

```
code      | account num | bill date
             100001        06-01-2013
             100001        06-01-2013
not found    100001        06-01-2013
             100001        06-01-2013
```

How could I not include these accounts into the total for not found? It there is an account with 1 not found and the rest errors then that is fine and an easy case. I guess the same problem will occur when checking for all errors as well.

Thanks for the help in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

Try the below query:

```
SELECT code, count(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT "Account number", max( code ) code
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY "Account number"
) alias
GROUP BY code
```

demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/8afc6/2

The query might look tricky ... it is based on an alphabetical order of status values:
1. error
2. not found
3. usefull
MAX(status) returns the last status (according to the above order) and ....... 
by accident it meets required conditions:
1. at least one **useful**
2. no useful, but at least one **not found**
3.  only **error**